# Contact Form 7 Spacing Issue

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNtHQ.png)

I am having an issue with the spacing between the last two fields "Your Message" and "Referred?" for some reason the spacing here is different than in between the other fields. Here is my code:

```
    <label> Your Name (required)
    [text* your-name] </label>

<label> Your Email (required)
    [email* your-email] </label>

<label> Subject
    [text your-subject] </label>

<label> Your Message
    [textarea your-message] </label>
<div id="referrals">
[checkbox checkbox-411 use_label_element "Referred?"]</div>

<label> [text text-739 id:answer-for-referrals]</label>

[submit "Send"]

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
// Select the container div by its ID
var container = document.getElementById('referrals');
// Get the input elements in the container
var checkbox = container.getElementsByTagName('input');
// Hide answer by default
document.getElementById("answer-for-referrals").style.display = 'none';
// Assign a function to onclick property of each checkbox
for (var i=0, len=checkbox.length; i<len; i++) {
  if ( checkbox[i].type === 'checkbox' ) {
    checkbox[i].onclick = function() {
    var check = 0;
    for(var j=0; j < checkbox.length; j++) {
    if (checkbox[j].checked === false) {
       check = 1;
    }
    }
    if(check === 0) {
    document.getElementById("answer-for-referrals").style.display = 'block';
    }
    else{
    document.getElementById("answer-for-referrals").style.display = 'none';
    }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Does the div with id `referrals` have any attributes we should know about?

Comment: Yes can you have any attribute for the referrals and you can try using removed the space for every div and check !